create an average distance matrix based on matching prefix column and row names in R
I want to create a new distance matrix from an array of hundreds of distance matrices. This new matrix will be the average distances given a set of pairwise distances. The values to be averaged is based matching name prefixes. Easier to illustrate as my language might be incorrect: Here's one sample distance matrix:
                    SpeciesA_1  SpeciesA_2   SpeciesC_1.  SpeciesC_2
SpeciesA_1      0       0.2         0.3     0.4

SpeciesA_2      0.2     0           0.4     0.5

SpeciesC_1      0.3     0.4         0       0.1

SpeciesC_2      0.4     0.5         0.1     0

I want the mean of all possible pairwise combinations given two prefix. For example:
SpeciesA_1 & SpeciesC_1 (0.3)
SpeciesA_1 & SpeciesC_2 (0.4)
SpeciesA_2 & SpeciesC_1 (0.4)
SpeciesA_2 & SpeciesC_2 (0.5)

Therefore, my resulting new distance matrix in this example should be:
           SpeciesA     SpeciesC
SpeciesA    0          0.4

SpeciesC    0.4         0


My actual matrices have about 140 columns and rows. I have no idea where to even get started with this. These dists are an array:
dists[,,i]

I can't use a loop (which I would normally start with by selecting the first name) because it is an array which I never work with.
dim(dists)
[1] 135 135 138

Here's an example of how I initially made the array of matrices and then filled them in:
labs <- c("A_1","A_2", "B_1", "B_2", "C_1", "C_3", "D_1", "D_3")

dists <- array(0, dim= c(length(labs),length(labs), length(tr)),dimnames=list(labs, labs))```


For testing, I've reduced my dataset to a smaller version for reproducibility and providing it here via dput: ```structure(c(0, 0.0636415002701785, 0.145334597498582, 0.163803183404822, 
0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 0.181754323491637, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0.0636415002701785, 0, 0.145334597498582, 0.163803183404822, 
0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 0.181754323491637, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0.145334597498582, 0.145334597498582, 0, 0.163803183404822, 
0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 0.181754323491637, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 
0, 0.054577752568928, 0.109103869804459, 0.181754323491637, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 
0.054577752568928, 0, 0.109103869804459, 0.181754323491637, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 0.163803183404822, 
0.109103869804459, 0.109103869804459, 0, 0.181754323491637, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0.181754323491637, 0.181754323491637, 0.181754323491637, 
0.181754323491637, 0.181754323491637, 0.181754323491637, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1.33332929092241, 1.33332929092241, 
1.33332929092241, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.33332929092241, 0, 0.222274233863968, 
0.444424503431041, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.33332929092241, 0.222274233863968, 
0, 0.444424503431041, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.33332929092241, 
0.444424503431041, 0.444424503431041, 0, 0, 0.0938002031509043, 
0.0938002031509043, 0, 0.0938002031509043, 0.167066002969562, 
0.167066002969562, 0.445943812443056, 2, 2, 2, 0.0938002031509043, 
0, 0.0317248785850623, 0, 0.0663652495301367, 0.167066002969562, 
0.167066002969562, 0.445943812443056, 2, 2, 2, 0.0938002031509043, 
0.0317248785850623, 0, 0, 0.0663652495301367, 0.167066002969562, 
0.167066002969562, 0.445943812443056, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0938002031509043, 0.0663652495301367, 0.0663652495301367, 
0, 0, 0.167066002969562, 0.167066002969562, 0.445943812443056, 
2, 2, 2, 0.167066002969562, 0.167066002969562, 0.167066002969562, 
0, 0.167066002969562, 0, 0.0896758431063197, 0.445943812443056, 
2, 2, 2, 0.167066002969562, 0.167066002969562, 0.167066002969562, 
0, 0.167066002969562, 0.0896758431063197, 0, 0.445943812443056, 
2, 2, 2, 0.445943812443056, 0.445943812443056, 0.445943812443056, 
0, 0.445943812443056, 0.445943812443056, 0.445943812443056, 0, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 1.49478622213262, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.49478622213262, 
0, 0, 0.16633562218756, 0.739785630571588, 0.739785630571588, 
0.739785630571589, 0, 0.739785630571589, 0, 0.739785630571589, 
1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 0.16633562218756, 0, 0.739785630571588, 
0.739785630571588, 0.739785630571589, 0, 0.739785630571589, 0, 
0.739785630571589, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 0.739785630571588, 
0.739785630571588, 0, 0.246730997741163, 0.493610100538917, 0, 
0.493610100538917, 0, 0.493610100538917, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 
0.739785630571588, 0.739785630571588, 0.246730997741163, 0, 0.493610100538917, 
0, 0.493610100538917, 0, 0.493610100538917, 1.33468159813059, 
1.33468159813059, 0.739785630571589, 0.739785630571589, 0.493610100538917, 
0.493610100538917, 0, 0, 0.165591599845893, 0, 0.329233335343189, 
1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.739785630571589, 0.739785630571589, 0.493610100538917, 
0.493610100538917, 0.165591599845893, 0, 0, 0, 0.329233335343189, 
1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.739785630571589, 0.739785630571589, 0.493610100538917, 
0.493610100538917, 0.329233335343189, 0, 0.329233335343189, 0, 
0, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 
1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 0, 1.33468159813059, 
0, 1.33468159813059, 0, 0.999452440298663, 1.33468159813059, 
1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 1.33468159813059, 
0, 1.33468159813059, 0, 1.33468159813059, 0.999452440298663, 
0), .Dim = c(11L, 11L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Az14", "Az14_3", 
"Az201", "Az201_3", "Az92", "Az92_3", "Am", "Am_3", 
"Ap02", "Ap02_3", "og"), c("Az14", "Az14_3", 
"Az201", "Az201_3", "Az92", "Az92_3", "Am", "Am_3", 
"Ap02", "Ap02_3", "og"), NULL))```


Your data example is not reproducible.

Using the array in the updated question (here it is x).
Get the row/column indices of each unique prefix (assumes row names = column names):
idx <- split(1:nrow(x), sapply(strsplit(rownames(x), "_"), "[[", 1))

Initialize the final distance matrix:
m <- array(0, c(rep(length(idx), 2), dim(x)[3]), rep(list(names(idx)), 2))

Calculate the mean distances for each combination of prefixes and put the values into m:
for (i in 1:(length(idx) - 1)) {
  for (j in (i + 1):length(idx)) {
    m[i, j,] <- m[j, i,] <-
      colMeans(x[idx[[i]], idx[[j]],,drop = FALSE], dims = 2)
  }
}

Result:
m[,,1]
#>             Am      Ap02      Az14     Az201      Az92        og
#> Am    0.000000 1.6666646 1.0908772 1.0908772 1.0908772 1.6666646
#> Ap02  1.666665 0.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 0.4444245
#> Az14  1.090877 2.0000000 0.0000000 0.1545689 0.1638032 2.0000000
#> Az201 1.090877 2.0000000 0.1545689 0.0000000 0.1228220 2.0000000
#> Az92  1.090877 2.0000000 0.1638032 0.1228220 0.0000000 2.0000000
#> og    1.666665 0.4444245 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 0.0000000
m[,,3]
#>              Am      Ap02      Az14     Az201      Az92        og
#> Am    0.0000000 0.4159787 0.3698928 0.2468051 0.0413979 0.6673408
#> Ap02  0.4159787 0.0000000 1.0372336 0.9141458 0.4159787 1.1670670
#> Az14  0.3698928 1.0372336 0.0000000 0.7397856 0.3698928 1.3346816
#> Az201 0.2468051 0.9141458 0.7397856 0.0000000 0.2468051 1.3346816
#> Az92  0.0413979 0.4159787 0.3698928 0.2468051 0.0000000 0.6673408
#> og    0.6673408 1.1670670 1.3346816 1.3346816 0.6673408 0.0000000

rowMeans(m, dims = 2)
#>              Am     Ap02      Az14     Az201      Az92       og
#> Am    0.0000000 1.360881 0.5890916 0.4969782 0.4731441 1.444668
#> Ap02  1.3608811 0.000000 1.6790779 1.3047153 1.4719929 1.119628
#> Az14  0.5890916 1.679078 0.0000000 0.3085786 0.2190901 1.778227
#> Az201 0.4969782 1.304715 0.3085786 0.0000000 0.1426616 1.444894
#> Az92  0.4731441 1.471993 0.2190901 0.1426616 0.0000000 1.555780
#> og    1.4446685 1.119628 1.7782272 1.4448939 1.5557803 0.000000
identical(rowMeans(m, dims = 2), apply(m, 1:2, mean))
#> [1] TRUE

As a function:
groupDist <- function(x) {
  idx <- split(1:nrow(x), sapply(strsplit(rownames(x), "_"), "[[", 1))
  m <- array(0, c(rep(length(idx), 2), dim(x)[3]), rep(list(names(idx)), 2))
  
  for (i in 1:(length(idx) - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):length(idx)) {
      m[i, j,] <- m[j, i,] <-
        colMeans(x[idx[[i]], idx[[j]],,drop = FALSE], dims = 2)
    }
  }
  
  m
}


this is great! except this isnt an array of matrices. It is a single matrix. dim(x) is [1] 35 35 while the dimensions of my array are 138 matrices dim(dists) =
135 135 138

Can you dput an example array of matrices?

Here's how I initially made the array and then filled in the matrices: dists <- array(0, dim= c(length(labs),                          length(labs),                          length(tr)),                dimnames=list(labs, labs))

So you want one output matrix for each matrix in the array (the third dimension of the input should match the output)? Are the row/column names identical between each input matrix?

Yes, that'd work! Then I create another new matrix of average patristic distances across all with the following:
avg_D <- apply(dists, c(1, 2), mean) 

I'm trying to make a list instead of an array to use a for loop on your code but I don't understand the backslash in your answer:m[lower.tri(m)] <- combn(idx, 2, \(i)  mean(x[i[[1]], i[[2]]])) . It results in "Error: unexpected input"

See the update. The backslash is an abbreviation for function.

rowMeans(dists, dims = 2) will be faster than apply(dists, c(1, 2), mean).

I'll accept this once (if) I get it to work with my data. I have an error still "Error in m[j, i, ] <- colMeans(dists[idx[[i]], idx[[j]], ], dims = 2) :
incorrect number of subscripts" dists is my array instead of your x. and I dont know how to use functions.

Please provide a small reproducible example.

What new example? I'm running the code provided (answer) given the dist I provided in the original question (the example of my data).

What is dim(dists) and dim(m) before you enter the for loops?

I'm testing on a small array of 3: ```dim(dists)
[1] 135 135   3
```dim(m)
[1] 68 68  3 ``` these numbers make sense because one column/row doesn't have an "_" on it (it's a single unique prefix)

I'm not sure what you mean by "one column/row doesn't have an "_" on it (it's a single unique prefix)". That could be the problem. It would help if you can make a fully reproducible example that returns the error.

I've reduced my dataset to a small test version and pasted in the question using dput @jblood94

See the update. The array indexing inside colMeans needed the drop argument set to FALSE. Since there was only one row/column with the og prefix, x[idx[[i]], idx[[j]],] would collapse to a 2-D array for j = 6, and colMeans didn't know what to do with it for dims = 2. Not the first time drop has gotten me.

drop = F fixed the issue! Indexing is still very, very challenging for me to understand the syntax but this is something for me to dissect now. Thanks so much.
